# Mongo and Rails newbie - trying to query for user and getting syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to query for user

```
user = User.("linkedin_accounts.uid" => "16268324").first
```

but I get this error:

```
irb):19: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting $end
user = User.("linkedin_accounts.uid" => "16268324").first
                                       ^
    from (irb):19
    from :0
```

What does it mean that its expecting end? How is my query wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you used is wrong. There should be a method after `User.`:

```
user = User.first("linkedin_accounts.uid" => "16268324")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now I got another error but this time its from the database so your answer was right.

Comment: yeah I was going to.. StackOverflow has a wait time before an answer can be accepted so I am waiting on that. :)